# Regexing lines from web page

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, urllib

```
import urllib2
import re

content=urllib2.urlopen("https://ipinfo.io/AS32244")
for line in content:
        ver_regex = re.compile(r"(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:/\d\d?)?")
        py2_ver = ver_regex.search(line)
        print(py2_ver)
```

I am using python 2.7.5 and I am getting none printed on every line.

What is the appropriate way to do search a pulled website?

I looked at BeautifulSoup but I don't think it works for me because of how the table is structured.

I know the regex does work though:
https://regex101.com/r/a3qE9A/1

Comment: What specifically are you attempting to read from the page?

Comment: Are you sure the `content` contains the right text? If yes, you just can use `re.findall(patter, content)`

Answer (score 1):

For me the code works, but prints out so many Nones that you don't notice the matches. After all, most lines don't match. This code shows the results clearly:

```
    py2_ver = ver_regex.search(line)
    if py2_ver:
        print(py2_ver.group())
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing each line, parse the whole thing at once:

```
import urllib2
import re

content = urllib2.urlopen("https://ipinfo.io/AS32244").read()
ver_regex = re.compile(r"(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:/\d\d?)?")
print ver_regex.search(content)
```

This will print the first occurrence of the number you are looking for or `None` if there is none. If you instead want to find all possible occurrences, use [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) instead of `search`